# ¿Cómo ingresar en el código Python, strings con texto de otra fuente distinta al alfabeto latino?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, fuentes

Tengo que comparar datos ingresados por botones, pero resulta que los botones tienen texto del **Alfabeto Fonético Internacional (International Phonetics Alfabet)**. Les muestro en la imagen algunos de dichos botones. La cuestión es que tengo en mi código un diccionario llamado *letters* que me ayudará posteriormente a la comparación, usando como clave, el mismo texto contenido en los botones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ven la imagen, podrán notar que es otra fuente, que se llama **SILDoulosIPA93**
Entonces la pregunta es ¿Cómo ingresar en el código Python, strings con texto de de esta fuente **SILDoulosIPA93**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve investigando tu problema y ese específico set de carácteres se **recomienda no usarlos**, por estar obsoletos y por haber mejores alternativas, [sin embargo, aquí hay un link de descarga de lo que ocupas ahora](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=encore-ipa-download); [y esto, es el nuevo set de carácteres que recomiendan usar para casos como el tuyo](https://software.sil.org/doulos/).

La mejor implementación que se me ocurre para poder captar el evento del click de un botón con un caracter de esos, es crear un diccionario que almacene una función para click de **cada botón, como la llave** y que el valor sea una letra del alfabeto en español/inglés, correspondiente al caracter del `SILDoulos IPA93`, así:

```
acciones_por_boton = {

boton1Clickeado: 'a',

boton2Clickeado: 'b',

**Sigue...**}
```

Lo siento por no poder darte un ejemplo práctico, pero estoy en el teléfono :P.

**EDIT** Por si alguien quiere saber cómo crear diccionarios que contengan funciones como sus valores/llaves, [ésto puede ser de mucha ayuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168340/using-a-dictionary-to-select-function-to-execute)

Suerte amigo.